# Grep and set -o errexit

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash-script. It finds a string in the file.

```
#/bin/bash

set -o errexit

grep 'findedstring' $file.
echo "was founded string on file"

<...>
```

If the string was found in the file the script was successfully executed and I can see *"was founded string on file"* in the output . 
But if the file doesn't have 'findedstring' then the script exits and didn't work further, so I don't see *"was founded string on file"* in the output 
If I will try to delete the following string in my script

> 'set -o errexit'

then the script will work further and I can see string *"was founded string on file"* in the output.

How can I save the string in script

> 'set -o errexit'

and my script will keep working when the string is not founded in the file?

Help me, please.

Comment: `$  set -o nonexit
bash: set: nonexit: invalid option name` ?

Comment: sorry, set -o errexit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep 'findedstring' $file. || true
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#/bin/bash

set -o errexit

[[ $(grep 'findedstring' "$file") ]] && echo "found string on file"

echo "I will be reached even if grep fails"
```

Comment: Assumed `.` in `$file.` is a typo